# Named return values are no longer supported error

Tags: c++, sorting, structure

With the code below, I am getting the following error:

> named return values are no longer supported return a.mark>b.mark;

Can anyone please help diagnose this error?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
struct student
{
    public:
    string name;
    int rank;
    int  mark;
    student()
    {
        mark=0;
    }
};

bool compare(student a,student b)
    return a.mark>b.mark;



int main()
{

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string*input=new string[n];
    student s[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        getline(cin,input[i]);
    }
    //string *name=new string[n];
    //int *nums=new int[n];
   // int *next_nums_pos=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int j=0;
        int count=0;
        int start=0;
        //nums[i]=new int[100];
        //next_nums_pos[i]=0;
        //nums[i]=0;
        int size=0; 
        while(input[i][j]!='\0')
        {
          if(count==0)
           {    
              if(input[i][j]==' ')
              {   
                s[i].name=input[i].substr(start,size);
                //cout<<name[i]<<endl;
                start=j+1;
                count++;
                size=0;
              }
              else
                size++;
           }
         else
           {
             if(input[i][j]==' ')
             {
                 int m;
                 stringstream mark(input[i].substr(start,size));
                 mark>>m;
                 s[i].mark+=m;
                 start=j+1;
                 size=0;
             }
             else
                size++;
           }

         j++;
        } 
         int m;
         stringstream mark(input[i].substr(start,size));
         mark>>m;
         s[i].mark+=m; 
    }
    sort(s,s+n,compare);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<" "<<s[i].name;
    }
    //cout<<name[0]<<endl;
    //for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     //   cout<<name[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put yourself in the position of someone reading this code for the first time, trying to imagine what is going on. As with most programming problems, you should try to recreate your problem using as little code as possible, until you isolate where the problem is. Your question's formatting is of very poor quality, this post should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Then you can focus on what the fix is, or ask people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I added {}, and it get fixed:

```
bool compare(student a,student b){
    return a.mark>b.mark;
}
```

You must use {} for functions, we can read and understand your code better and you never see this kind of errors.